# unable to connect LWM2M using wakaama client

Tags: iot, emq, lwm2m

I am using Emqx V3.1.1. And I am integrating LwM2M plugins.

For testing the same I installed Wakaama client in the same server and created build using cmake. I loaded the plugin now plugin is running.

Which I tried to run the below command

```
./lwm2mclient -n ep1 -h localhost -p 5783 -4
Trying to bind LWM2M Client to port 56830
LWM2M Client "ep1" started on port 56830
> Opening connection to server at localhost:5783
 -> State: STATE_REGISTERING
 -> State: STATE_REGISTERING
 -> State: STATE_REGISTERING
 -> State: STATE_REGISTERING
 -> State: STATE_REGISTERING
 -> State: STATE_REGISTERING
 -> State: STATE_BOOTSTRAP_REQUIRED
lwm2m_step() failed: 0xA3
```

I have followed the below link

https://github.com/emqx/emqx-lwm2m

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the port to 5683, which is the default port of lwm2m.
2. Make sure `allow_anonymous = true` in the emqx.conf

Answer (score 0):

You need a bootstrap server, take a look at *examples/bootstrap_server/* on *eclipse/wakaama* git repo.

Comment: I have Bootstrap server also in wakaama. below is the path /etc/wakaama-1.0/examples/bootstrap_server/

Comment: Dumb question: is it running?

Comment: you mean The plugin port What i have configured with emqx right ?

Comment: lwm2m plugin port is 5683 is running

Comment: Nope, I mean the bootstrap_server. You need it and lwm2mserver to be up and running, otherwise your client cannot be configured and you get the STATE_BOOTSTRAP_REQUIRED error.

Comment: your correct I tried below command ./lwm2mclient -n ep1 -h leshan.eclipseprojects.io -p 5683 -4      it is working But when i give localhost only it is not working. Here my doubt is how can i start bootstarap server

Comment: Now I am able to connect to my localhost. I am trying to test with different Msg types likes read discover write execute and delete. read and  discover are working . for write and remaining msg types I need below parameters. (Value type, period min,period max,step,greaterThan, lessThan,Arguments).

Comment: Well, you can ask another question about that (it is no longer related to this question). Remember to upvote useful answers and mark the questions as resolved. Thank you.

Comment: Bootstrap server is not mandatory in case you start in factory bootstrapped mode.